# Which item is making me fly in Binding of Isaac?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I'm midway through a run of Isaac, and I just realised that I can fly. I swear none of the items I have grant me flight, can anyone explain this for me?

[image].

Meanwhile I'm flying

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have become [Guppy](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Transformations#Guppy), which grants you the equivalent to [The Mulligan](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/The_Mulligan), which spawns blue flies when you deal damage, and the ability to fly.

This is because you have picked up 3 Guppy items that game: the Dead Cat, Guppy's tail, and Guppy's Head.